# Apache Camel route to sequential process

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have two routes:

1 - read from a queue and create a resultObject

2 - wait until a particular file is created inside a folder and than modifiy the resultObject from route 1. The result will be send in a queue.

What is the best way to concatenate these two routes?

At the moment I have:

```
public class FirstRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(myqueue)
            .process(exchange -> {
                // prepare ResultObject
                // add to camel context the second route that is initializated with resultObject
                SecondRouteBuilder secondRouteBuilder = new SecondRouteBuilder(resultObject);
                camelCtx.addRoutes(secondRouteBuilder);
                camelCtx.start();
            });
    }
}
```

```
public class SecondRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public SecondRouteBuilder (ResultObject result){
        this.resultObject = result;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(waitingAFileFromDirectory)
            .process(exchange -> {
                // process the file using the resultObject
            })
            .to(resultQueue);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want or need to do with the `resultObject`. In case you need to wait on the availability of a certain lock-file to consume a file you can use `doneFile` on a file consumer if you need to aggregate certain data from that file with the resultObject.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate them by [pollEnrich](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/content-enricher.html) and [loopDoWhile](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/loop-eip.html)

- `pollEnrich` to get the file
- `loopDoWhile` to control the file obtain behaviour

```
public class CombineRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(myqueue)
            .process(exchange -> {
                // prepare ResultObject and save to exchange property
            })
            .loopDoWhile(simple(<boolean gate to control file obtain strategy>))
                .pollEnrich(AFileFromDirectory)    // get your file
                // maybe a process to control boolean gate of loopDoWhile
            .end() // end loop
            .process(exchange -> {
                // process the file using the resultObject from exchange property
            })
            .to(resultQueue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it good to use loopDoWhile for monitoring when a particular file is created?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If you 100% sure the file will exist and obtainable at the time you get, then `loopDoWhile` can be omitted. Otherwise, the `loopDoWhile` will help ensure the file is collected before moving to next step.